# is it possible to control beep sound of scanner?

Tags: c#, serial-port, barcode-scanner, honeywell

Hi Im C# Developer and i have 2d scanner (Honeywell Solaris 7980g) with serial port communication .

My Application scan the QRCode and as a time scanner scan the code , by default scanner play beep sound .

i want to play beep sound after checking code in my server.

i have test these two solutions :

1 : notify user by show my validation on my form by custom color (ex:red) 

2: notify user by play error sound in my app

but i want to control scanner sound to play beep after my validation, any idea?

is it possible to control beep sound of scanner ?

thanks .

Comment: Maybe you can show us what you tried so far and what your code looks like...

Comment: Have you tried  Any code for playing a beep sound?

Comment: no , i don't have idea how to play beep sound on scanner , i just play it on my app (with speaker) , is it possible to control beep sound of scanner ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the scanner to "Beep on BEL Character" by sending the command BELBEP1.  After this command, when the scanner receives a BEL character (hex 07), it will beep.

Comment: thanks sir , can you help me how to send command to my scanner in c# ?

Comment: Unofrtunately not, but make sure to read the "Serial Programming Commands" section in the technical reference guide, since you must follow a specific protocol when sending commands.  You can not just send the string "BELBEP1".

Comment: that was exactly right -->

byte[] bytestosend = { 0x07 };
serialPort1.Write(bytestosend, 0, bytestosend.Length);